# Ionic - Remove Disable spinner on splash screen

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen

How can I disable the splash screen spinner during the startup of an Ionic app?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

If it is a SplashScreenSpinner:

In the `config.xml` file:

```xml
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
```

[Official Docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen)